# Using flexbox with height 100vh and object-fit

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y000489a/3/)

I want to archive the following layout:

```
 _____________________________
[ img using up the            ]
[ rest of the available space ]
[                             ]
[                             ]          
[_____________________________]
[          Button 1           ]
[          Button 2           ]
[          Button 2           ]
[_____________________________]
```

- The height of the flexbox should be 100vh
- The buttons should be aligned to the bottom of the page
- The image should use the rest of the available space, scale down and get some padding when the image ratio does not match.

I tried the following:

```css
.myflex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  object-fit: contain;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
  flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="myflex">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-421-856-10.jpg" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <div>
      button1
    </div>
    <div>
     button2
    </div>
    <div>
      button3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is now, that the image doesn't seem to know what the available space of the view port is and is partially outside the visible area.

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: reset the `body` margin by `body{margin: 0;}` ?

Comment: why not just use flex: 1; ?

Comment: It seems like even when flex-direction is set to column, images are still sized to width. I thought there would be a flexbox way to do this but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out flexbox and ass @kukkuz suggested, set body margin to 0

```
body {
  margin: 0
}

.myflex {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.buttons {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
img {
  flex: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 0;
}

.buttons {
  flex: none
}
```

or you can take the `<img/>` in a new flex box